# UnRARing files in Python in OSX

Tags: python, macos, unrar

This is driving me nuts, I've looked at & tried a number of the answers here for solving this problem but nothing is working out so far.

The basic problem is that I have some 1300+ rar files that I'd like to extract and keep somewhat organized, and to make things more fun a number of the rar files contain more rar files (which is why I'm disinclined to just do this by hand).

My first attempt, I just figured I'd do a simple python script that would just call unrar directly:

```
import os
import glob
import string
import subprocess

fileCount=0
files = glob.glob('Archives/*.rar')

for file in files:
  print file

  callstring = ["/usr/local/bin/unrar","e",file]
  output = subprocess.check_output(callstring)
  print output
```

This code returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Overlord/Documents/python/Unpacker.py", line 25, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(callstring)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/unrar', 'e', 'testFile.rar']' returned non-zero exit status 10
```

(anyone know what error code 10 means?)
Using unrar from the command line works without any problem.

Secondly I tried using libarchive, but despite a lack of build errors, I couldn't get the library to import.

Next I went with pyunpack:

```
from pyunpack import Archive

files = glob.glob('Archives/*.rar')

for file in files:
  print file
  Archive(file).extractall(".")
```

This threw a "no such file or directory" error.

```
EasyProcessError: start error <EasyProcess cmd_param=['patool', 'extract', Path(u'/Users/Overlord/Documents/python/testFile.rar'), Path(u'--outdir=/Users/Overlord/Documents/python')] cmd=['patool', 'extract', Path(u'/Users/Overlord/Documents/python/testFile.rar'), Path(u'--outdir=/Users/Overlord/Documents/python')] oserror=[Errno 2] No such file or directory returncode=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout=False>
```

Then I tried patoolib:

```
import patoolib

files = glob.glob('Archives/*.rar')

for file in files:
  print file
  patoolib.extract_archive(file,outdir=".")
```

This one threw the following:

```
PatoolError: could not find an executable program to extract format rar; candidates are (rar,unrar,7z)
```

Despite this message when I run patool directly from the command line the file is unrar'd with no problems.

So I went back to the original subprocess solution and tried using patool instead of unrar

```
import subprocess

fileCount=0
files = glob.glob('Archives/*.rar')

for file in files:
  print file

  callstring = ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/patool","extract",file]
  output = subprocess.check_output(callstring)
  print output
```

And got back the following:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/patool', 'extract', 'testFile.rar']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Any thoughts or suggestions while I still have a few hairs I haven't pulled out of my head?

Comment: Are you showing us the correct code? The filename that gives an error is `testFile.rar`. But your glob is `Archives/*.rar`. So the filename *should be* `Archives/testFile.rar`. So my guess is that you're either cutting off the directory or using a non-existent filename.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I copied and pasted from the wrong sample code. The errors remained the same, however. The code that gave the error actually changed directories into the archive directory before calling unrar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`rarfile`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile) library here:

**Install:**

```
$ pip install rarfile
```

**Example:**

```
from rarfile import RarFile

with RarFile("myarchive.rar") as rf:
    for f in rf.infolist():
        with open(f.filename, "wb") as of:
            of.write(rf.read(f))
```

**Update:** Alternatively you can just "extract all" in one step by doing:

```
from rarfile import RarFile


with RarFile("myarchive.rar") as rf:
    rf.extractall()
```

Comment: No problems! Seems like a nice little library/wrapper :) Please accept this if you find it acceptable and working!

Comment: Playing around with it, I think I found a slightly simpler construction: 
`from rarfile import RarFile
with RarFile("myarchive.rar") as rf:
      rf.extracall()`

Comment: I guess it depends if you want to do any processing on each file before writing them out or perhaps renaming them or what not :)